# Handle multiple HTTP connections and a heavy blocking function like SSH

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, tornado, gevent

**Scenario**:

My server/application needs to handle multiple concurrent requests and for each request the server opens an ssh link to another m/c, runs a long command and sends the result back.

1 HTTP request comes → server starts 1 SSH connection → waits long time → sends back the SSH result as HTTP response

This should happen simultaneously for > 200 HTTP and SSH connections in real time.

**Solution**:

The server just has to do one task, that is, open an SSH connection for each HTTP request and keep the connection open. I can't even write the code in an asynchronous way as there is just one task to do: **SSH**. `IOLoop` will get blocked for each request. Callback and deferred functions don't provide an advantage as the ssh task runs for a long time. Threading sounds the only way out with event driven technique.

I have been going through tornado examples in Python but none suit my particular need:

1. tornado with twisted
2. `gevent`/`eventlet` pseudo multithreading
3. python threads
4. established HTTP servers like Apache

**Environment**:

Ubuntu 12.04, high RAM & net speed

**Note**:
I am bound to use python for coding and please be limited to my scenario only. Opening up multiple SSH links while keeping HTTP connections open sounds all asynch work but I want it to look like a synchronous activity.

Answer (score 0):

If by `ssh` you mean actually running the ssh process, try `tornado.process.Subprocess`.  If you want something more integrated into the server, twisted has an asynchronous ssh implementation.  If you're using something like paramiko, threads are probably your best bet.

Comment: in simple terms the code should start a ssh for each http request it gets and keep it open too.i think i do need threading and so am still undecided should it be gevent cooperative threads or actual python threads from twisted.probably mix of callback and threading is needed in this.the ssh connection will be running for pretty long time plus i need the output to be sent as the http response.